# Laravel create a table of relations between models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `Subscriber` model defined as such:

```
class Subscriber extends \Eloquent {
    public static function scopeConfirmed($query)
    {
        return $query->where('confirmed', '=', 1);
    }

    public function codes()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('Code');
    }
}
```

A `Meme` model:

```
class Meme extends \Eloquent {
    public function codes() {
        return $this->hasMany('Code');
    }
}
```

And a `Code` model that they are connected through:

```
class Code extends \Eloquent {
    public function subscriber() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Subscriber');
    }
    public function meme() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Meme');
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is a table that has `Meme`'s as columns and `Subscribers` as rows that would show if a code exists that belongs to a `Subscriber` and `Meme`. Using a foreach to achieve that is inefficient and I think there is a way to do that in eloquent.

```
|-----|Meme 1|Meme 2|Meme 3|
|Sub 1|  0   |   0  |   1  |
|Sub 2|  0   |   1  |   1  |
|Sub 3|  1   |   1  |   0  |
```

Many thanks

Comment: Isn't it just many to many relations between Subscriber And Meme with some extra data in pivot table (Code)? What does Code actually represent?

Comment: @StasMakarov A code is sent to the user so that he can access the Meme, as a part of an individual link (think marketing emails). It is individual to the user and specific Meme.

Comment: So you want to be able to connect a Subscriber to a Meme through a Code?

Comment: @Helliax Kind of, yes. And show that relation on a matrix table like in the OP.